# OAuth within non browser application?

Tags: oauth, desktop-application

I know how OAuth works in web applications that run in a browser, but I'm not sure how OAuth can be implemented in an application that does not run in a browser.

It's easy to display the URL using some kind of a WebView, but how do I get back the information it sends back? My research doesn't reveal a straightforward way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few Java libraries out there that can do this.  (Are you looking for a particular language?)

Scribe is probably the most mature Java library:
https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java

There are more libraries for pretty much every language here:
http://oauth.net/code/